# How to style html using ajax?

Tags: ajax, html, jquery-mobile

I have this code in the ajax success function. I want to change the font size. Do I need to do it in css? How do I declare it? How about if I want to do something like list in ajax. Is that possible? Because if it is in the list, it will in the square box. any suggestion?

```
     html  = '<h1 align=center>#######################################</h1>';
     html += '<h1 align=center>          Course Details               </h1>';
     html += '<h1 align=center>#######################################</h1>';
     html += '<h3><br>' +json_results.rows[courseId].courseName+'</br></h3>';
     html += '<br> Registration #    : ' + json_results.rows[courseId].regNo+'</br>';
     html += '<br> Status            : ' + json_results.rows[courseId].regStatus+'</br>';
     html += '<br> Location          : ' + json_results.rows[courseId].courseLoc+'</br>';
     html += '<br> Start Date        : ' + json_results.rows[courseId].startDate+'</br>';
     html += '<br> Registered Person : ' + json_results.rows[courseId].fullName+'</br>';
     html += '<br> Rate              : ' + json_results.rows[courseId].rate+'</br>';
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add classes to that markup....instead of deprecated align=center, you could add class="ajaxh1" or something. better yet, since that's all a var, just add a wrapping div or related semantic element with a class, then you can target them all.

Answer (score 0):

yes, if you assign css classes to the h1 and h3 tags you will then display this information in whatever style you describe.